# how to transfer all the key value pairs present in a .txt file to an array using bash script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, jq

I have a variable "var" which has the json text as shown below

```
 var='{ "user": "jack","password": "kilby","install":"False", "deploy":"False", "build":"123","ip":"0.0.0.0" }'
```

Iam writig that to a .txt file

```
touch properties.txt

destdir=./properties.txt

if [ -f "$destdir" ]
then 
    echo "$var" > "$destdir"
fi
```

Then I have to store all key value pairs inside an array for further processing that i am dong as below

```
arr=( $(grep -o \"[^\"]*. properties.txt) )
```

So all the texts present inside double quotes are moved to "arr"

but the problem is if key value pair is as shown below i.e if value is empty then "arr" is getting  \"  as a one entry, Thats not desiarble.

```
{"k1":"","k2":"","k3":""}
```

I need an empty string to go inplace as an entry to "arr" in such case.

I am not much aware of bash commands. So appreciate any help.
If the result can achieved using "jq" library then those suggestions are also welcome.
thanks

Comment: what is the desired output and what is the output you get with your code?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou all i am doing  is storing all the key values into an array from a txt file that contains json string. Remember Its not a json file

Comment: What is a JSON file if not a text file that contains valid JSON?

Comment: .txt file here will not have proper line endings such as newline after each key value pair. It will just have a json string. Like "var"( that i a have mentioned in the question).

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
$ jq -c 'keys[] as $k | ($k, .[$k])' <<< "$var"
"build"
"123"
"deploy"
"False"
"install"
"False"
"ip"
"0.0.0.0"
"password"
"kilby"
"user"
"jack"
```

You can then use the bash command, `readarray`, or the idiom:

```
while read -r line
do ...
done
```

See the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ) for further details.

#### Caveat

You don't say what your ultimate goal is, but I suspect that you would be better off using jq more comprehensively to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

`jq` is the tool to parse JSON from shell. You can parse JSON in other languages (python, php, ruby, GO, etc), but if you go that route, you might as well just write your whole program in that language.

So .. from bash, you'd use `jq`:

```
$ jq 'keys[] as $k | "\($k)=\(.[$k])"' <<<"$var" 
"build=123"
"deploy=False"
"install=False"
"ip=0.0.0.0"
"password=kilby"
"user=jack"
```

If you want these pairs in an associative array in bash 4+, you might do this:

```
$ declare -A a="( $(jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "[\($k)]=\"\(.[$k])\""' <<<"$var" ) )"
$ declare -p a
declare -A a=([build]="123" [install]="False" [ip]="0.0.0.0" [user]="jack" [deploy]="False" [password]="kilby" )
```

This works fine as long as there are no newlines in variable indexes or values. To make it handle more complex data, you'll need .. a more complex handler. If there's a risk of newlines, please mention it in your question.

Comment: ++ for the `declare -A` approach: I had no idea you could initialize arrays this way.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>This answer's solutions read the key-value pairs into *consecutive* elements of a *regular* array (element `0` receives the 1st key, element `1` the associated value, ...), as in the question; for a solution that creates a Bash v4+ *associative* array, see [ghoti's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42322295/45375).</sup>

**tl;dr**:

#### Using standard utilities only:

```
readarray -t arr < <(grep -o '"[^"]*.' properties.txt | tr -d \")
```

Bash v3.x equivalent:

```
arr=()
while IFS= read -r val; do
  arr+=( "$val" )
done < <(grep -o '"[^"]*.' properties.txt | tr -d \")
```

#### Using `jq`:

```
readarray -t arr < <(jq -r 'keys_unsorted[] as $k | $k, .[$k]' properties.txt)
```

<sup>The `jq` command is a variation of [peak's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42317877/45375): `keys_unsorted` ensures that the keys are enumerated in input order, and `-r` ensures that the results are output as raw values rather than JSON-encoded, which in this case means that the double quotes are stripped.</sup>

Bash v3.x equivalent:

```
arr=()
while IFS= read -r val; do
  arr+=( "$val" )
done < <(jq -r 'keys_unsorted[] as $k | "\($k)\n\(.[$k])"' properties.txt)
```

---

First things first: if feasible, it's **always worth using a proper JSON parser such as [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)**.

The problems with your approach:

- `grep -o \"[^\"]*.` *included* the enclosing `"` in the output, which the array assignment `arr=( ... )` then parsed as *part of the values*.
- It's easy to fix that problem by piping to `tr -d \"` to remove them, but the `arr=( $(...) )` syntax then *ignores empty strings*, so you'll lose empty input values in the process.
- That said, you should *generally avoid* `arr=( $(...) )`, because it 
  (a) invariably splits the output from the command substitution `$(...)` by *whitespace* (word-splitting), irrespective of embedded quote chars., (b) by default subjects the resulting words to filename expansion (globbing).

The safe alternative that avoids both problems - at least with *line-oriented* input - is to use `readarray`, available since Bash v4.0; `-t` strips the trailing `\n` from the lines read.

In Bash v3.x, a `while` loop must be used to read the lines, because the construct that is *almost* equivalent to `readarray -t arr` - `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra arr` - also *ignores empty entries*.

Answer (score -1):

First I will make a function that returns the contents of the array.

```
function myvar {
   cat << "END"
{ "user": "jack","password": "kilby","install":"False", "deploy":"False", "build":"123","ip":"0.0.0.0" }
END
}
```

Now we can parse the var by cutting the string in lines at ',', and find the fields.

```
myvar | tr ',' '\n' | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*\(".*"\).*/\1=\2/'
```

Now we have these, we can evaluating the result by sourcing it. Before sourcing it, we will use a tick to make it act as a file: `<( echo "My output looks like a file")`
OP asked for an array, but first I will show how to make environment vars.

```
source <(myvar | tr ',' '\n' | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*\(".*"\).*/\1=\2/')
echo "Environment variable build=${build}"
```

Now we like to fill it in an associative array (Note: bash version 4 only).

```
declare -A arr
source <(myvar | tr ',' '\n' | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*\(".*"\).*/arr[\1]=\2/')
# Show that it worked
for key in ${!arr[@]}; do
     echo "Array[${key}]=${arr[${key}]}"
done
```

Comment: I did not get a reason for the downvote, but I think I know. My solution is not resistent against small changes in layout of the input, using a tool that understands json is better. I did post this answer for showing help for other people reading the question "how to transfer all the key value pairs present in a .txt file to an array using bash script" without having a json inputstring.

Answer (score -1):

Without wanting to judge if the method you selected to parse that kind of data is right or wrong, i will try to answer your question even if i disagree with your selected method for parsing json data.

In this point of your code you create an array named arr:

```
arr=( $(grep -o \"[^\"]*. properties.txt) )
```

If you ask bash to tell you what is stored inside this array you get the response:

```
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="\"user\"" [1]="\"jack\"" [2]="\"password\"" [3]="\"kilby\"" \
[4]="\"install\"" [5]="\"False\"" [6]="\"deploy\"" [7]="\"\"" \
[8]="\"build\"" [9]="\"123\"" [10]="\"ip\"" [11]="\"0.0.0.0\"")
```

Mind that i have modified the var field `"deploy":"false"` to `"deploy":""` to test my answer - this is arr[7] above.

The most easy way i found to handle the missing fields from your array is to redifine the same arr array using bash substitution techniques like this:

```
$ arr=( ${arr[@]//\"\"/\"empty\"/} )
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="\"user\"" [1]="\"jack\"" [2]="\"password\"" [3]="\"kilby\"" \ 
[4]="\"install\"" [5]="\"False\"" [6]="\"deploy\"" [7]="\"empty\"/" \
[8]="\"build\"" [9]="\"123\"" [10]="\"ip\"" [11]="\"0.0.0.0\"")
```

Mind that arr[7] has changed to `"empty"` from previously `""`

In reality, your code will store to the array the string `\"\"` for empty fields, which will be printed by echo like simple `""`

After my substitution , declare -p advises `arr[7]=\"empty\"` , which will be printed by echo as simple `"empty"`.Of course you can change this text to whatever you like, by maintaining the escaping of double quotes.

Results with your second `var2={"k1":"","k2":"","k3":""}`

```
$ var2='{"k1":"","k2":"","k3":""}'
$ echo "$var2" >properties.txt
$ cat properties.txt
{"k1":"","k2":"","k3":""}
$ arr=( $(grep -o \"[^\"]*. properties.txt) )
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="\"k1\"" [1]="\"\"" [2]="\"k2\"" [3]="\"\"" [4]="\"k3\"" [5]="\"\"")
$ arr=( ${arr[@]//\"\"/\"empty\"/} )
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="\"k1\"" [1]="\"empty\"/" [2]="\"k2\"" [3]="\"empty\"/" [4]="\"k3\"" [5]="\"empty\"/")
$ echo "${arr[@]}"
"k1" "empty"/ "k2" "empty"/ "k3" "empty"/
```

Notice:
This solution is only advising the next step to your code. I have not tested your data manipulation techniques (i.e your grep, etc).

Comment: @BeatrixKiddo I suppose you had in mind something like assigning default values in bash (see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value). These techniques are not  operating in your case since your entries are not considered empty according to bash logic.

Answer (score -1):

Thnaks a lot for quick response guys. I solved my problem by following method

```
makeKeyValueArray (){
# remove colon and commas
IFS=':' read -ra ADDR <<< "$var"
IFS=',' read -ra ADDR2 <<< "${ADDR[@]}"

echo ${ADDR2[@]} > "$destdir"

#remove curly braces
sed 's/[{}]//g' $destdir > temp_ip_prop.txt
mv temp_ip_prop.txt $destdir



#store each item in a array "arr"
    cn=0;
        for i in `cat $destdir`
        do
        arr[$cn]=$i;
        ((cn=cn+1));
        done

}
```

And then in a loop i compared whether array contains "". If so i just made that field as empty space.

The mistake i was doing was in the

> arr=( $(grep -o \"[^\"]*. properties.txt) )

This was storing each \" to the array.